# IEEEtran, longtable, switch to one column mode for the appendix

Tags: longtable, two-column, appendices, ieeetran

I've this very long table to put in the appendix of a 2 column, IEEEtran conference paper. I'm trying to use longtable, but apparently longtable has to be used in one column mode only.

Is there a way to switch to one column for the appendix only?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
blah...

\appendix

\begin{longtable}[t]
blah...
\end{longtable}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can interrupt two column mode by issuing the command `\onecolumn`; however, you might want to issue `\clearpage` prior or `\newpage` before you do so. 
Then when you are done with the long table you can re-instate two column mode with `\twocolumn`.

If this doesn't work in `IEEEtran`, you could probably do `\usepackage{supertabular}` and use the floating `supertabular` environment to break up the two column.  The `supertabular` documentation says the `*` variant works like `tabular*`.