# How to make multi-page tables in IEEEtran format?

Tags: tables, longtable, ieeetran, supertabular

How can one create a table that spans multiple pages using the `table` environment in IEEEtran format? I'm currently using `tabular` inside a `table` environment. But my table is getting too long.

I've referred [IEEEtran, longtable, switch to one column mode for the appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126855/ieeetran-longtable-switch-to-one-column-mode-for-the-appendix), but it does not reside in a table environment and hence doesn't have captions or labels for reference.

`longtable` doesn't seem to work, nor does `supertabular`. May I have an minimum working exampl on how to do this?

- The table takes up both columns of the page.
- I require the features of the `table` environment: label, title, and caption.

Comment: Does your table take up one column or both columns?

Comment: Yes, @hbaderts; I've made the necessary edit to the question.

Answer (score 4):

"doesn't seem to work" is not very informative. What did you try and what error did you get?

This works, for example.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}


see table \ref{zzz}.

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\appendix

\begin{longtable}{c|c}
\textbf{A}&\textbf{B}\\
\caption{a long table\label{zzz}}
\endfirsthead
\textbf{A}&\textbf{B}\\
\caption*{a long table (continued)}
\endhead
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\a&b\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Carlisle. Well, the point is that it works outside the `table` environment but only the first part of it's visible when its nested within `table` environment. The remaining part goes to oblivion. I really need the features provided by the `table` environment: caption, label, and title. Is there an alternative for a longtable?

Comment: The example with `longtable` by David Carlisle does contain a caption and a label.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac no you do not need `table` please _look_ at the example above it uses a caption and label and a working `\ref`.

Comment: Sorry, Mr. Carlisle, I think I've overlooked it. Yes, you're right, it works well with caption and label-ref. Is there a way to do this without switching back and forth between `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`?

Comment: not with  longtable, it only does one column (but you said in your question that you want a single table to span both columns,so that is OK.

Comment: Actually, I'm including the table in one of the middle sections of my paper. When I switch back and forth between column modes, I get a half-full page before and and after the table. Is there any suggestion you can make to solve this? If not, I'm thinking of retrofitting it with text content instead.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac not with longtable. You could try supertabular instead

Comment: May I know change to make to use a `supertabular`?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac there are _dozens_ of examples of supertabular and longtable on this site, please just use the search box, there is nothing specific to ieeetran in your question.